# Zend framework 2 session exists or not, in Module.php

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to call the session in public function `onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)` function in Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
    if( $user_session->offsetExists('user_email_id')){
       //code here
     } 
    else {

            header("Location: ". $this->serverUrl() . "/register");


        }

}
```

How can i achieve this?

i am not getting the `echo $this->serverUrl();` inside the `OnBootstrap` function

Answer (score 1):

There a number of problems with this code.

- You need to create a new session container (`Zend\Session\Container`) to set/get your session data.
- You are trying to set headers manually, although this would work, there are better ways to do so in ZF2.
- Redirection in the `onBootstrap` method is probably not the best 'time' to do so.
- You attempt to use a *view helper* in `Module.php` (`\Zend\View\Helper\ServiceUrl`) to redirect. View helpers <del>can</del> should only be called in the view. You can use them, however you would need to fetch it via the ViewPluginManager, rather than using `$this->`.

With these points in mind I would consider adding a event listener either late `onRoute` or early `onDispatch`.

For example:

```
namespace FooModule;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\BootstrapListenerInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module implements BootstrapListenerInterface
{
    public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $event)
    {
        $application  = $event->getApplication();
        $eventManager = $application->getEventManager();

        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, [$this, 'isLoggedIn'], 100);
    }

    public function isLoggedIn(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $data = new Container('user');

        if (! isset($data['user_email_id'])) {

            $serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
            $controllerPluginManager = $serviceManager->get('ControllerPluginManager');

            // Get the \Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Redirect
            $redirect = $controllerPluginManager->get('redirect');

            return $redirect->toRoute('some/route/path', ['foo' => 'bar']);
        }
        // use $data here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, bu i am getting the following error. Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Users\Module::isLoggedIn() must be an instance of Users\EventInterface

Comment: @blackbishop : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Stdlib\Exception\InvalidCallbackException' with message 'Invalid callback provided; not callable' in C:\wamp\www\health\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Stdlib\CallbackHandler.php on line 62

Comment: @markwinkle Sorry the first one was correct. I'm not sure, but I think the parameter for `onBootstrap()` and `isLogged()` should be `MvcEvent $event`.

Comment: Appolgies, I hadn't tested the code. The correct type hint for the [`onBootstrap` method is `\Zend\EventManager\EventInterface`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Feature/BootstrapListenerInterface.php), you will need to add use statement at the top of the class e.g `use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface` or the fully qualified class name as the type hint.